# SQL that access accepts, but SQL Server Express rejects

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-server-express

Today I wrote this bit of sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(T0021_werk_naam)
FROM (SELECT Distinct T0021_werk_naam,T0021_jaar,T0021_kwartiel
    FROM T0021_offertes
    WHERE T0021_status_code = 'G' AND T0021_jaar = 2013 AND (T0021_kwartiel = 3))
```

This sql runs great when I run it locally in access, however, when I run it through the code that has been used for ages for this and most certainly definetly is not the problem, and send it to SQL Express it gives an error that says there's a problem near ')'
After stripping away all the brackets possible it becomes clear that it detects there's a problem with the last ')' but I don't see the problem.

Any Ideas?

Comment: All I know is in MySQL all derived tables need to be aliased. So you can just add any character at the end of the query to act as an alias for the subquery (derived table). Though if that is the case, then SQL Express really gives crappy error messages :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give an alias for the select in the parenthesis:

```
SELECT COUNT(T0021_werk_naam)
FROM   (
           SELECT Distinct T0021_werk_naam,
                  T0021_jaar,
                  T0021_kwartiel
           FROM   T0021_offertes
           WHERE  T0021_status_code = 'G' 
                  AND T0021_jaar = 2013 
                  AND (T0021_kwartiel = 3)
       ) T
```

notice the T in the end after the last parenthesis.

Comment: Now I feel silly XD Thanks a bunch! SQL is so confusing to me sometimes, especially with all the slight differences in syntax!

Comment: btw, I thought you gave aliases by doing `AS T` but just T suffices?

Comment: Yes it is the same thing.

Comment: alright, well, great! :D I'll except your answer in 5 mins, the site's telling me to wait :\